# Upload files to cloudinary from url via js

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

I want to upload (copy) a file from a known url to Cloudinary from client-side javascript code without using any file upload UI. How can it be done?

I read the docs but just couldn't understand how this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following syntax:

```
$('.cloudinary_fileupload').cloudinary_upload_url(url);
```

This will initiate an upload request to Cloudinary with the url as instead of a local file.

Comment: So I have to pass all the other arguments in the `<input>` field? It seems a little awkward

Comment: The common use-case is widgets where a user can either upload a local image or give a remote url. Thus the configuration is done once on the input tag for both cases.

Comment: Calling `$('.cloudinary_fileupload').cloudinary_upload_url(url);` produces following error response - `{"error":{"message":"Missing required parameter - file"}}`. Any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong? I think I should mention is that I overrode fileupload `add` method to manually trigger upload by calling `data.submit()`.

Comment: Once again, thanks for your help Tal. For those who are having same issue, brief problem description and solution can be found here: [http://support.cloudinary.com/entries/26830108-Cloudinary-jQuery-plugin-upload-from-URL](http://support.cloudinary.com/entries/26830108-Cloudinary-jQuery-plugin-upload-from-URL)